# Enveloping XML Digital Signature Generator Commercial Tool

Tags: xml, signature

Is anyone aware of a commercial tool that can generate and validate digital XML *enveloping* signatures?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Signature xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
<SignedInfo>
  <CanonicalizationMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/TR/2001/REC-xml-c14n-20010315" />
  <SignatureMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#rsa-sha1" />
  <Reference URI="#object">
    <DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#sha1" />
    <DigestValue>OPnpF/ZNLDxJ/I+1F3iHhlmSwgo=</DigestValue>
  </Reference>
</SignedInfo>
<SignatureValue>nihUFQg4mDhLgecvhIcKb9Gz8VRTOlw+adiZOBBXgK4JodEe5aFfCqm8WcRIT8GL
LXSk8PsUP4//SsKqUBQkpotcAqQAhtz2v9kCWdoUDnAOtFZkd/CnsZ1sge0ndha4
0wWDV+nOWyJxkYgicvB8POYtSmldLLepPGMz+J7/Uws=</SignatureValue>
<KeyInfo>
  <KeyValue>
    <RSAKeyValue>
      <Modulus>4IlzOY3Y9fXoh3Y5f06wBbtTg94Pt6vcfcd1KQ0FLm0S36aGJtTSb6pYKfyX7PqC
      UQ8wgL6xUJ5GRPEsu9gyz8ZobwfZsGCsvu40CWoT9fcFBZPfXro1Vtlh/xl/yYHm
      +Gzqh0Bw76xtLHSfLfpVOrmZdwKmSFKMTvNXOFd0V18=</Modulus>
      <Exponent>AQAB</Exponent>
    </RSAKeyValue>
  </KeyValue>
</KeyInfo>
<Object Id="object"><ActualXMLDocument/></Object>
</Signature>
```

Answer (score 0):

Altova XMLSpy 2019 Enterprise supports it:

https://www.altova.com/manual/XMLSpy/spyenterprise/index.html?xsxml_xmlsigs_creating.htm